# If Date exists then show next date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has all dates where events occur, but I just want to show the next event that occurred if a date exists in another table.

Here's my logic - I have two tables:

**table_1**

```
userid     date          event
01         2018-01-01    A
01         2018-01-02    A
02         2018-01-01    A
03         2018-01-01    B
```

**table_2**

```
userid     date
01         2018-01-01
02         NULL
```

What I have so far:

```
SELECT t1.userid, t1.date
FROM table_1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 as t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
WHERE 1.event = 'A'
```

Basically, I want to figure out if `table_2.date is not null` then show `table_1.date` where `table_1.date > table_2.date`

The result should look like:

```
userid     date
01         2018-01-02
```

Since userid 01 has a date value in table_2, so I got the date that's greater then the date in table_2.

Comment: You wrote most of the logic right into your question. Just use a left join and you should be 99.999% of the way there.

Comment: I think this could use a little more detail. Can the same `userid` occur multiple times in `table_2`? If so, how does this affect the expected results? Also, you wrote that you want the "next event"—singular. Does that mean that, for instance, if `table_1` had an additional record with `userid = 01` and `date = 2018-01-03`, the expected results would still include only the 2018-01-02 event for that user?

Comment: @JoeFarrell sorry for the confusion. The userid in table_2 will only show once. It will, however, show multiple times in table_1. I will add more details. Basically table one has an identifier for the even that will show in table_2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go for a correlated subquery:

```
select t2.*,
       (select top (1) t1.date
        from table1 t1
        where t1.userid = t2.userid and t1.event = 'A' and t1.date > t2.date
        order by t2.date desc
       ) t1_date
from table2 t2
where t2.date is not null;
```

Comment: This answer totally worked, thanks! I'm using the subquery you shared twice, for 2 columns, one to show the date and one to show the type of event. I know I didn't mention that in the initial question, but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: @kazzi . . . Can you ask another question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table_1 t1
where event = 'A' and
      exists (select 1 
              from table_2 t2
              where t2.userid = t1.userid and 
                    (t2.date is not null and t1.date > t2.date));
```

However, `is not null` filter is redundant here you can simplfy it directly as

```
where event = 'A' and
      exists (select 1 from table_2 t2 
                       where t2.userid = t1.userid and t1.date > t2.date);
```